# Show that $\text{ker}(T^*T)=\text{ker}(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

> Show that $\text{ker}(T^*T)=\text{ker}(T)$

---

In my solutions when showing that $x\in\text{ker}(T)\implies x\in\text{ker}(T^*T)$ the following is given:

$$x\in\text{ker}(T)\implies Tx=0\implies T^*Tx=0\implies x\in\text{ker}(T^*T)$$

How exactly does $Tx=0\implies T^*Tx=0$ ?

Comment: $T^*$ is a linear map so $T^*Tx = T^*0 = 0$

Comment: Where is the operator $T$ defined? What function space are you working on?

Comment: T a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space. I see my error now as clarified by the first comment and answer.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T^*$ is a linear operator, hence $T^*(0)=0$.